# Calculate the difference between two dates in php 5.2

Tags: php

I want to calculate the difference between two dates

```
$startDate = date_create(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$targetDate = date_create('2018-01-30 11:00:00');

$result = strtotime($targetDate) - strtotime($startDate);
$result = (int) $result;

echo $result;
```

but returned

> Warning: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /home/info.php on line 50

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: So you have to pass a string to strtotime(). What do you think date_create() returns? Is it a string?

Comment: Why don't you use the `DateTime()` class.

Comment: You should really consider upgrading your php version!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the date_create function altogether. date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); is returning a string which is the input that strtotime expects. Tested using php 5.2.17 at the sandbox link below.

```
$startDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$targetDate = '2018-01-30 11:00:00';

$result = strtotime($targetDate) - strtotime($startDate);

$result = (int) $result;

echo $result;
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9c59a5cb098eb80b355b947e394b3b0446852df3

Comment: thanks, i solved , remove the date_create function altogether